# using a variable in addConstraint produces a wrong answer but not using variables works fine

Tags: python, lambda, constraint-programming

my code is working if done like so

```
from constraint import *
import itertools
def main():
    problem = Problem()
    x = [0,1,2,3]
    f = list(itertools.product(x,x,x,x))

    problem.addVariable("a", f)

    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[0] == a.count(0), "a",)

    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[1] == a.count(1), "a",)

    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[2] == a.count(2), "a",)

    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[3] == a.count(3), "a",)    

    solutions = problem.getSolutions()
    print "Found %d solutions!" % len(solutions)
```

the answer would be `[{'a': (2, 0, 2, 0)}, {'a': (1, 2, 1, 0)}]`

but if I use variables it goes haywire

```
from constraint import *
import itertools
def main():
    problem = Problem()
    x = [0,1,2,3]
    f = list(itertools.product(x,x,x,x))

    problem.addVariable("a", f)

    x = 0
    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[x] == a.count(0), "a",)
    x = 1
    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[x] == a.count(1), "a",)
    x = 2
    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[x] == a.count(2), "a",)

    problem.addConstraint(lambda a: a[3] == a.count(3), "a",)  

    solutions = problem.getSolutions()
    print "Found %d solutions!" % len(solutions)
```

which results to an empty list. I want to be able to put this in a loop but I don't know what's going on. I may just be missing something very basic but it only works if I use real numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you "add variables", the values are looked up with the lambda functions are *called*, not when they are defined.  In this case, I'm guessing they don't get called until `problem.getSolutions()` which means that the value of `x` will be `2` in each of your function calls (instead of `0`, `1` and `2` respectively as in the initial code).

This is a [very common "gotcha"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) in python code and you can fix it by setting a default argument (as those get evaluated once, when the function is created).

```
lambda a, x=x: a[x] == a.count(0)
```